# Access Core Data ModelContainer with SwiftData

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have an app that uses CoreData and I want to migrate to SwiftData. After following the [Migrate to SwiftData](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10189) session, I only need to point to my old Core Data file to read the old data and convert it to the new SwiftData format.

**My question is how do I do this?** Maybe worth mentioning is that my `NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")` is different to my app name.

---

### Possible Solution?

According to a [Tweet by Donny Wals](https://twitter.com/DonnyWals/status/1668538920051539968) this is done this way:

> By default a SwiftData ModelContainer will create its underlying storage in a file called `default.store`. If you want to change this so you can use an existing Core Data SQLite file, you can point your container to that file instead:
>
> ```
> // point to your old sqlite file
> let url = URL.applicationSupportDirectory.appending(path: "Model.sqlite")
> let config = ModelConfiguration(url: url)
>
> modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: [
>    Movie.self
> ], config)
> ```

#### My Tested Code

```
@main
struct SwiftData_TestApp: App {
    let url = URL.applicationSupportDirectory.appending(path: "Model.sqlite")
    let config = ModelConfiguration(url: url)
    
    let modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: [
        Item.self
    ], config)

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(modelContainer)
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I don’t get it to work in the main app struct. When using this the way described in [Dive deeper into SwiftData](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10196?time=418) (at 6:58) I only get the error: `Cannot use instance member 'url' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

PS: There seems to be an issue with this WWDC session method anyway – [see here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732030).

Comment: That error has nothing to do with SwiftData or Core Data. Add an `init` and initialize your properties there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Joakim Danielson in the comments, the issue was the wrong initialization:

```
@main
struct SwiftData_TestApp: App {
    let url = URL.applicationSupportDirectory.appending(path: "Model.sqlite")
    let modelContainer: ModelContainer

    init() {
        do {
            modelContainer = try ModelContainer(
                for: [Item.self],
                configurations: ModelConfiguration(url: url))
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize model container.")
        }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(modelContainer)
    }
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@main
struct SwiftData_TestApp: App {   

    var body: some Scene {

    let url = URL.applicationSupportDirectory.appending(path: "Model.sqlite")
    let config = ModelConfiguration(url: url)
    
    let modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: [
        Item.self
    ], config)
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(modelContainer)
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).